# React JS: Inserted div (mapbox map) doesn't stretch inside a full div block

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a modal (div) which I'd like to insert my map which itself is a div. So basically everything is working fine, but I've got a problem which occurs on every device. The modal gets displayed, but the map doesn't stretch to full size, but when I zoom in or out, the map stretches itself to a full height and width, how can I fix it?

Map element:

```
<div ref={(el) => (this.mapContainer = el)} style={{ width: '100%', height: '70vh' }}></div>
```

[This is how it is in action (MP4)](https://gyazo.com/dd924ed8c2f96df46fc7a1a5b19724fc)

Comment: can you show a bit more code please?

Comment: Since the mapbox is rendered as an iframe, you can set the `width` and `height` of it to `100%` so it fits the modal.

Comment: @EvgenyKlimenchenko which part do you need to see?

Comment: @nadz after adding the styling to the Map element inside the modal, I got these results https://gyazo.com/31532b7d25cfc34d571607407d2493ee

Comment: @DziugitoBizox Did you apply it to the iframe? if so and it's still not affected, try adding an `!important` tag like - `width: 100% !important;` to overwrite the default width and height added inline.

Comment: what do you call iframe? I've added the styling to <Map /> element inside the modal div.

Comment: @DziugitoBizox see if this helps. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229900/discussion-between-nadz-and-dziugito-bizox).